# root = Tk() TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter

hello everyone im a newbie at python and i learn tkinter so easy on me

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

mylabel = Label(root, text="Hello world :)")

mylabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

this is my code when I run this code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\New Folder Of Desktop\Python Project\gui.py", line 1, in <module>    
    from tkinter import *
  File "e:\New Folder Of Desktop\Python Project\tkinter.py", line 4, in <module>
    root = Tk()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

this error showup can someone help me pls ?

Comment: You should not call your own files `tkinter.py`. This will make all your modules import that file instead of the real `tkinter`.

Comment: There is another file named `tkinter.py` it seems, `from tkinter import *` tries to import that, and not the builtin module.

Comment: so i have change name ? or what ?

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend not having file names that can clash with the names of modules.

Comment: yesssss it work, thank you Talon,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Expansion from previous comment

Let this be your Directory structure:

```
E:\New Folder Of Desktop\Python Project\
 - gui.py
 - tkinter.py
```

In `gui.py`, you have the like `from tkinter import *`. When python does this, is searches multiple directories for some module with the name `tkinter`. You can see the list of places where this module is searched by checking `sys.path`

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

The first place searched is the current directory, the place where your installed modules are is typically near the end. When you have a python file with the same name in the current directory, the search is stopped and this will be imported instead of the one you installed. Some more info on importing [here](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/python-import-syspath-and-pythonpath-tutorial).

Renaming the conflicting file is the easiest approach.

You *could* mangle with the `sys.path` list and remove the current directory or such tricks, but I would not recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to not make your file with the name tkinter.py I had tried everything else but this was the problem.